# How to work with utf-8 characters in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

While I have seen that you can have utf-8 encoding in sqlite3, which I guess would enable you to ingest and store data that is utf-8 encoded, it seems like it is not possible to use sqlite3 command tool with sqlite3 characters and thus in essence making it very hard to work with utf-8 data (let alone column names, just filtering data is implossible).

If I open up sqlite3 or any sqlite3 database in terminal and try to press any of "æøå" (nordic characters) none of them register as in the shell. Is there a way to work with sqlite3 and utf-8 characters in terminal? I work in ubuntu and use SQLite version 3.32.3.

By suggestion of @Panagiotis Kanavos I ran `$ locale` output:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
LANGUAGE= 
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_NUMERIC=nb_NO.UTF-8 
LC_TIME=nb_NO.UTF-8 
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MONETARY=nb_NO.UTF-8 
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_PAPER=nb_NO.UTF-8 
LC_NAME=nb_NO.UTF-8 
LC_ADDRESS=nb_NO.UTF-8 
LC_TELEPHONE=nb_NO.UTF-8 
LC_MEASUREMENT=nb_NO.UTF-8 
LC_IDENTIFICATION=nb_NO.UTF-8 
LC_ALL=
```

My language being eng-us.utf8 might explain it? I will change and update this post if that fixes it.

Comment: Sounds like the *real* question is how to display UTF8 bytes correctly in your terminal? SQLite text is always Unicode.

Comment: What does `$ locale` return on your terminal? I suspect the locale settings don't use `UTF-8`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Interesting - it is only in sqlite3 I cannot write UTF8 bytes correctly - which is frustrating as I have to work with data with them in. (It works if I write the query in a file or do the query in a third party program).
`$ locale`
```LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_TIME=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_NAME=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=nb_NO.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```